# MYSQL get all grouped results one one query with a row count

Tags: php, html, mysql, left-join, inner-join

So I have searched everywhere for this but I can't find this specific relation. The query below returns all posts from a user and the number of people who liked the post because I used a GROUP BY `postid` meaning that if the result repeat themselves but have the same `postid` then they are grouped.

---

```
SELECT posts.id postid,posts.post_body,posts.post_type, ALLUSERS.USERNAME,
       likes.liker,likes.target,
       plikers.*,
       COUNT(posts.id) numberOflikes

FROM posts
INNER JOIN ALLUSERS ON(ALLUSERS.USERID=posts.FROM_userid)
LEFT JOIN likes ON(likes.target=posts.id)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT USERID pl_id FROM ALLUSERS )plikers ON(pl_id=likes.liker)
GROUP BY postid
```

And the result is...

```
+--------+-----------------+------------------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| postid | post_body       | post_type              | USERNAME  | liker | target | pl_id | pl_un     | numberOflikes |
+--------+-----------------+------------------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+---------------+
|     83 | Southgate       | 20&&03 Saturday/04:05  | Superuser |  NULL | NULL   |  NULL | NULL      |             1 |
|     84 | Great post!     | 10&&03 Saturday/04:07  | Superuser |     4 | 84     |     4 | dennisrec |             7 |
|     85 | How delightful? | 10&&03 Saturday/04:07  | Superuser |    43 | 85     |    43 | zerCon    |             1 |
|     87 | Cheers...       | 10&&07 Wednesday/01:53 | Superuser |  NULL | NULL   |  NULL | NULL      |             1 |
|     88 | check this out! | 20&&07 Wednesday/03:31 | Superuser |  NULL | NULL   |  NULL | NULL      |             1 |
+--------+-----------------+------------------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

Which is right but this only returns the first result of the grouped.
So the quest stands, Is there any way to **return all results of all groups in one query**?

Now clearly I could just remove the `GROUP BY` and the `count(*)` phrase then `get multiple duplicate results` then filter them to get all details of the `likers` of the post but that would surely slow my servers down. So I've already tried that.

Any help would pretty much be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(likes.liker)..`. But, the capacity of  `GROUP_CONCAT` needs to be adjusted if your data size grows.

Comment: Your current query doesn't make sense because you are selecting non aggregate columns with a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it does make sense and i get results affected by "GROUP BY"  but it groups everything and selects the first result of the every group and if i remove that it returns all results but with duplicate rows that matched yet i just wanted to grab only the userid field from the likers table.  what's so hard to understand?

Comment: Which `post_body` do you want to display for each post group?  This isn't clear, and currently you are allowing MySQL to freely choose a value.  Note that your query might not even run on all versions of MySQL, nor on most other databases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it works in many mysql versions, that i have checked already. The `post_body` is the obviously the body of every post. So when i select post_body i also left join table `likers` to get number of people who liked the post and also their details perhaps. Now u got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model looks like this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from posts;
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| id   | post_body | post_type | from_userid |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 | POST1     | NULL      |           1 |
|    2 | POST2     | NULL      |           2 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from likes;
+------+--------+-------+
| id   | TARGET | liker |
+------+--------+-------+
|    1 |      1 |     3 |
|    2 |      1 |     7 |
|    3 |      2 |     8 |
|    3 |      2 |     6 |
+------+--------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from users where id < 9;
+----+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| id | userName | photo     | status | ts                  |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | John     | john.png  |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  2 | Jane     | jane.png  |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  3 | Ali      |           |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  6 | Bruce    | bruce.png |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  7 | Martha   |           |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  8 | Sidney   |           |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then as @1000111 suggests you can

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT  posts.id postid,posts.post_body,posts.post_type,POSTS.FROM_USERID
    ->  , USERS.USERNAME
    ->        ,GROUP_CONCAT(likes.liker) LIKER
    ->  ,likes.target
    ->  ,GROUP_CONCAT(plikers.pl_id) pl_id
    ->        ,GROUP_CONCAT(plikers.UNAME) pl_un
    ->  ,COUNT(posts.id) numberOflikes
    ->
    -> FROM posts
    -> INNER JOIN USERS ON USERS.ID=posts.FROM_userid
    -> LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.target=posts.id
    -> LEFT JOIN(SELECT ID pl_id, USERNAME UNAME FROM USERS )plikers ON pl_id=likes.liker
    -> GROUP BY postid;
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+--------------+---------------+
| postid | post_body | post_type | FROM_USERID | USERNAME | LIKER | target | pl_id | pl_un        | numberOflikes |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+--------------+---------------+
|      1 | POST1     | NULL      |           1 | John     | 7,3   |      1 | 7,3   | Martha,Ali   |             2 |
|      2 | POST2     | NULL      |           2 | Jane     | 6,8   |      2 | 6,8   | Bruce,Sidney |             2 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+--------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but you should be mindful of the caveat

Comment: You the only person who understood the problem i presented! Thanks very much that makes perfect sense.